# What is the recommended way to make a four-dot ellipsis?

Tags: typography

For a three-dot ellipsis, it is recommended to use the ellipsis character, …, but I can't seem to find any four-dot ellipsis character, for example as recommended by the MLA style guide for when more than one sentence is omitted. What is recommended to look consistent with the three-dot ellipsis characters in my document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the recommendation isn't to have a 4-dot ellipse but rather to have a period and an ellipsis.

> Hello, world.…That is what the man said.

That is semantically correct (the sentence ends, then text is omitted and replaced with the ellipsis.

I would try that in whatever font I was using first and see if it looks ok. If the appearance of the period + ellipsis had strange spacing, I would remove it and type 4 periods instead, and then manually kern them so that the spacing between dots matched an actual ellipsis in that font.

Related question: [Why is an ellipsis represented by one single character rather than a sequence of kerned dots?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69277/why-is-an-el-lip-sis-represented-by-one-single-character-rather-than-a-sequence)

Comment: I'm pretty sure MLA suggests using all periods (with spaces between) for ellipsis anyway